# fGn asymptotic claim correlation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $(X_{i})$ be the fractional Gaussian noise for $H\in(0,1)$.
Since it is stationary $\mathbb{E}(X_{i}X_{j})$ only depends on $|j-i|$.
How can I prove for $\rho(|j-i|)=\mathbb{E}(X_{i}X_{j})$ that the following relation holds:
$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}\rho(j-i)\sim Kn^{2H}$ with a constant K?

Comment: Of course  I have to use $\rho(j-i)\sim K|j-i|^{2H-2}$ but how can I complete the proof?

Comment: It would be very nice to get a hint.